# XML RSS to HTML parser doesn't work

Tags: xml, apache, programming-languages

I'm using MCX (I don't even know if someone here is familiar with it, pretty unkown derivate of COBOL and Fortran, look it up in google when you don't believe me)

Note: I'm using MCX on the MCX-WebServices server as it does neither support apache or ISS, mabye that is one problem.

The thing is that I want to use the XML library to read in an XML file and convert it into an output format readable by the user.
The XML lib already has all the functions I need for that, yet my program fails.

```
#!usr/bin/mcx
$PGRM.ID: index.mcx
$PGRM.AT: /mstr

SHOWERROR:
 WRITE XML.LastError --> OUTPUT
 DO_FLUSH
 xcit
 end\

MAIN:
 IMPORT Extras.XML
 USE Extras

 $XML_RSS_FILE: XML.ReadIn "rss.xml"

 ! $XML_RSS_FILE --> GOTO SHOWERROR

 $XML_RSS: XML.FormatRSS1 <-- $XML_RSS_FILE

 ! $XML_RSS --> GOTO SHOWERROR

 WRITE $XML_RSS --> OUTPUT
 DO_FLUSH
 FLUSH
 xcit
 end\
```

Program output: Nothing
The rss.xml file 100% exists and is readable

- What is wrong with this program?
  At least there should be displayed something, as I used FLUSH, but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Orchadsky has solved this problem in his seminal paper on [Optimally non-working electronics](http://c.editingmyspace.com/files/en/april.fools/april_fool_016.jpg). You'll find your answer there.